# Apollo Client refetch strategy

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

Consider the following queries

```
gql`
  query GetDogs {
    dogs {
      id
      breed
    }
  }
`;
```

```
gql`
  query GetDogsInfo {
    dogs {
      id
      name
      color
      createdAt
    }
  }
`;
```

```
gql`
  query GetDogsShort {
    dogs {
      id
      name
      image
    }
  }
`;
```

In all of these queries, We fetch `dogs` with different fields.

When I have a mutation, I need to refetch all of these queries.
I can refetch `['GetDogs','GetDogsInfo','GetDogsShort']`, but consider a complex application. If I add additional `dogs` query in my app with different fields I have to change refetch list again.

What is the best strategy to solve this problem? Consider that we cannot fetch all of the fields and reduce queries to a single query

Comment: Have you considered fetching the modified fields and `id` from your mutation result? Then you wouldn't need to refetch anything at all, it would be updated in the normalized cache.

Comment: The API response doesn't include all of the related fields that need to be refetched because of complexities